# How input_iterator_tag is different from forward_iterator_tag?

Tags: stl

How std::input_iterator_tag is different from std::forward_iterator_tag?

Inspired by SO answers about C++ iterators. Both tags seem to be appropriate in same cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can set values through a forward iterator.  `*iter = foo;` is legal in an *output* iterator, but not an input iterator, whereas a forward iterator can both read and write, unless it is *immutable*.

   ```
   const SinglelyLinkedList myList = foo();
   // a const container should return immutable iterators
   SomeIterTypedef immutableIter = myList.begin();
   ```
2. An input iterator can wrap the output of a function.  Forward iterators "can be used in multi-pass algorithms".  Two copies of a forward iterator should produce the same results unless the underlying container changes.  Input iterators don't even have to be associated with a container... istream_iterator for example.

I distilled all that from [the SGI iterators page](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html) and the specific input, output, and forward iterator pages.